# Get Address when click on map view

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, uitextfield, nsstring

I am making an application for iPhone. In that I want to add event like as when user click on map then that address save in text field of view. I have am showing map in view and user zoom in map and click on any location. When click on map then I want use that location. I want to save that location in string or text field. Can you tell me any API which provide this facility?
So can you tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [Location awareness](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and come back if you still need help.